# SQL. most commonly booked room type

Tags: sql, group-by

My tables:

```
 1. Hotel - city, hotelNo[pk]
 2. Room - roomNo[pk], type, hotelNo[fk]
 3. Booking - roomNo[fk], hotelNo[fk],date
```

And I want to show the most commonly booked room type for each hotel in London(hotel.city='London')

The code I found from the Internet were all like this

```
SELECT hotelno, type, MAX(y)
FROM
(SELECT hotelno, type, COUNT(type) AS y
FROM booking b, hotel h, room r
WHERE r.roomno = b.roomno AND
r.hotelno = b.hotelno AND
b.hotelno = h.hotelno AND
city = 'London'
GROUP BY hotelno, type)
GROUP BY hotelno, type;
```

It returns three columns hotelno, type and max(y). And all the booking times of each type of each hotel. I just want gets the most booking one type for each hotel. How can I do this? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Can't you just not use `MAX(y)` ?

Comment: you can just add a select top *** in the most outer query and that should work

Comment: I have given you and answer. If it does not solve your question, then please add example data and further description to the question so we can understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten my answer, to fix all the problems. This is the query:

```
SELECT hotelno, type
FROM
(SELECT hotelno, type, COUNT(type) AS y
FROM booking b, hotel h, room r
WHERE r.roomno = b.roomno AND
r.hotelno = b.hotelno AND
b.hotelno = h.hotelno AND
city = 'London'
GROUP BY hotelno, type) t
where not exists
(SELECT 1
FROM booking b2, hotel h2, room r2
WHERE r2.roomno = b2.roomno AND
r2.hotelno = b2.hotelno AND
b2.hotelno = h2.hotelno AND
h2.city = 'London'
GROUP BY b2.hotelno, r2.type
having b2.hotelno = t.hotelno and count(*) > y);
```

Basically I do the same grouping in the where as in the from.